# Omaha hi pre flop hand values

Tags: omaha

I am trying to find something similar to this https://caniwin.com/poker/omahahilopreALL.php for just for Omaha Hi.  Does anyone know where I can find one? Or direct me to a python script to be able to print one?

I tried writing one, but my system crashes, and feel others have done this.  Below is my script

```
from itertools import combinations
from phevaluator import evaluate_omaha_cards


def rank_omaha_hands():
    print("Ranking Omaha Starting Hands from Best to Worst:")

    deck = list(range(52))
    hands = []
    rank_count = 0

    for board in combinations(deck, 5):
        remaining_cards = set(deck) - set(board)
        for hand in combinations(remaining_cards, 4):
            rank = evaluate_omaha_cards(*board, *hand)
            hands.append((hand, rank))
            rank_count += 1

    hands.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    for i, (hand, rank) in enumerate(hands):
        card_names = [card_name(card) for card in hand]
        print(f"{i + 1}. Hand: {', '.join(card_names)}\tRank: {rank}")

    print(f"\nTotal number of evaluated hands: {rank_count}")


def card_name(card):
    ranks = "23456789TJQKA"
    suits = "cdhs"
    rank = ranks[card // 4]
    suit = suits[card % 4]
    return rank + suit


if __name__ == "__main__":
    rank_omaha_hands()
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out by importing a high lo hand and exporting a script, here is the StackOverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76560792/4180276